# Needing assistance in prepping for a Drupal Migration with Manifest.yml

Tags: drupal, migration, yaml

I am attempting to make a migration from D7 to D8 using Migrate Manifest. I have all the migrate modules installed (i.e. the 3 core migrate modules, Migrate Upgrade, Migrate Plus, Migrate Tools and Migrate Manifest). I followed the directions at this link: https://www.drupal.org/node/2350651 to prepare my manifest file. This is the relevant part of my resulting yaml file (truncated for brevity):

```
 - block_content_body_field
 - block_content_entity_display
 - block_content_entity_form_display
 - block_content_type
 - d7_block
 - d7_custom_block
```

When I ran the migrate-manifest via Drush, as specified by the directions in the link above, I received an error declaring a parse error pointing to the first line in the yaml list. This is the exact error: Unable to parse at line 1 (near " - block_content_body_field").

I tried several debugging steps:

- I checked a yaml linter to see whether my file was properly formatted. My file passed the test.
- I moved the block migrations below the ones that are prefixed with a 'd7' to match the example in the link.
- I attempted a piecemeal migration of a file from my list of migrations, it worked.
- I tried to alter the spacing on the list items.

All these steps failed to resolve the issue I am seeing.

I am unsure what other debugging steps I should take. All the above failed to resolve my issue.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: My first idea for you: add a question to your post, as this is a Q&A site that is quite appropriate. The second idea: leave out the appreciation announcement. That (and other things that don't make your question better understandable, like thanks, greetings, etc.) is not considered appropriate. Third idea: there is a space before the `-`, if that is really a space that is correct YAML, however if it is a TAB character, then it is not. Maybe you could include a hex dump of your first line in the post.

Comment: I have a non-tabbed space before the hyphen preceding each list item.  I also tried two spaces. Also, sorry for not explicitly stating my question: what do you do when you get a parse error despite having a seemingly correct format to your YAML file?